# Make a function to get the page number of a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a page index of one worksheet, which has about 1500 rows to trace back the information. My idea is to build up either a function or a code block to realize this function. Unfortunately, both don't work. The code I add to my programm is written by  Allen Wyatt (https://excelribbon.tips.net/T011581_Page_Numbers_in_VBA.html). It works if the pagenumber is shown with MsgBox. I want either, it works as a function, with that I get the pagenumber of a random cell (just to enter the cell address of this worksheet) or to integrate it into my loop programm to fill the index with page numbers.

I don't understand why the both methodes don't work. As fuction it only shows invalid value. As the value to loop the chaptern numbers, I only get the page number as 1.

Can any guru explain to me the reason?

Thanks a lot!

1.Function:

```
Public Function showpagenumber() As Integer

    Dim iPages As Integer
    Dim iCol As Integer
    Dim iCols As Integer
    Dim lRows As Long
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim iPage As Integer


    iPages = ExecuteExcel4Macro("Get.Document(50)")

    With ActiveSheet
        y = ActiveCell.Column
        iCols = .VPageBreaks.Count
        x = 0
        Do
            x = x + 1
        Loop Until x = iCols _
          Or y < .VPageBreaks(x).Location.Column
        iCol = x
        If y >= .VPageBreaks(x).Location.Column Then
            iCol = iCol + 1
        End If

        y = ActiveCell.Row
        lRows = .HPageBreaks.Count
        x = 0
        Do
            x = x + 1
        Loop Until x = lRows _
          Or y < .HPageBreaks(x).Location.Row
        lRow = x
        If y >= .HPageBreaks(x).Location.Row Then
            lRow = lRow + 1
        End If

        If .PageSetup.Order = xlDownThenOver Then
            iPage = (iCol - 1) * (lRows + 1) + lRow
        Else
            iPage = (lRow - 1) * (iCols + 1) + iCol
        End If
    End With

   showpagenumber = iPage

End Function
```

2. Code in programm, with that I only get the page number 1.

   ## ...

   ```
       For i = chapterstart To chapterend
       emptyrow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws2.Range("D:D")) + 1
           If Not IsEmpty(ws1.Cells(i, "A")) And IsNumeric(ws1.Cells(i, "A")) Then
                   iPages = ExecuteExcel4Macro("Get.Document(50)")
                   With ws1
                       y = ActiveCell.Column
                       iCols = .VPageBreaks.Count
                       x = 0
                       Do
                           x = x + 1
                       Loop Until x = iCols _
                         Or y < .VPageBreaks(x).Location.Column
                       iCol = x
                       If y >= .VPageBreaks(x).Location.Column Then
                           iCol = iCol + 1
                       End If

                       y = ActiveCell.Row
                       lRows = .HPageBreaks.Count
                       x = 0
                       Do
                           x = x + 1
                       Loop Until x = lRows _
                         Or y < .HPageBreaks(x).Location.Row
                       lRow = x
                       If y >= .HPageBreaks(x).Location.Row Then
                           lRow = lRow + 1
                       End If

                       If .PageSetup.Order = xlDownThenOver Then
                           iPage = (iCol - 1) * (lRows + 1) + lRow
                       Else
                           iPage = (lRow - 1) * (iCols + 1) + iCol
                       End If
                   End With

                   ws2.Cells(emptyrow, "D").Value = iPage

           End If
       Next
   ```

Comment: Your function `showpagenumber` does work when called from the immediate window. And also the message box is working when the code is implemented as proposed by Allen Wyatt. But something is seriously wrong here ....

Comment: Comment the line iPages = ExecuteExcel4Macro("Get.Document(50)") and your function does work! Don't ask me why!

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. At least I know now, what will not work and will not waste time on the further solution.